# setTimer() & timeInterval() in sencha don't work in Android & iPhone device

Tags: android, iphone, sencha-touch, settimeout, setinterval

I am working on a sencha touch application where I need to send request to server after every 1 min. I am using setInterval() & setTimeOut() both works in chrome on desktop but when it comes to iPhone or Android it don't work (they don't get called)
  Has anyone used these functions before (successfully) or any other functions to use.

Code used

```
  setInterval(function(){
     //server calling method
  },10000);

  setTimeout(function name,10000);
```

Function name is function which has code to send request to server.

Thank YOu

Comment: setTimeout is working fine on one of my project, are you sure it is called ?

Comment: it works for few seconds like it get called only in startup then it stop working.

Comment: Could you post the whole code so we can take a look at it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you Sencha's [DelayedTask](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.util.DelayedTask) class for the purpose? It will be something like this:

```
//create the delayed task instance with our callback
var task = Ext.create('Ext.util.DelayedTask', function() {
    //server calling method

    // The task will be called after each 10000 ms
    task.delay(10000);
}, this);

//The function will start after 0 milliseconds - so we want to start instantly at first
task.delay(0);

//to stop the task, just call the cancel method
//task.cancel();
```

And, I worked with this code with Phonegap and it worked fine.

Answer (score -3):

In iPhone generally NSTimer is used.

```
NSTimer *timer_main = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0) target:self selector:@selector(yourfunction) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

This will work in iPhone..

Comment: @Arpit -- Thanks for quick solution but I am working in sencha touch so I don't think NSTimer will work...